# Como quebrar a linha em uma string no VBA?

Tags: string, vba, excel-vba

Estou com dificuldades de colocar uma quebra de linha dentro de um texto de e-mail automatizado pela macro.

Crio o e-mail com o seguinte cód:

```
    "Necessitamos dos extratos do mês de " & Format((Month(Now) - 1), "mmm") & " das seguintes contas: " & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & "  Empresa: " & empresa1 & "  CNPJ: " & cnpj1 & vbNewLine & _
    tipoConta & vbNewLine & "  Conta: " & conta1 & "  Agência:  " & agencia1 & _
    vbNewLine & "  Empresa: " & empresa2 & "  CNPJ: " & cnpj2 & vbNewLine & _
    tipoConta & " : " & vbNewLine & "  Conta: " & conta2 & "  Agência:  " & agencia2 & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    "<FONT SIZE = 1.1><b>Essa mensagem foi gerada automáticamente e pode conter dados privados.</p></b>" & vbNewLinee & _
    "<FONT SIZE = 1><b>E-mail gerado por Amadeu Gustavo | 55 5555-5555</p></b>"
```

**Coloquei a chave depois do quebra de linha para melhor visualizar**

e o e-mail gerado respeita só um dos comandos de quebra de linha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O seu e-mail está sendo enviado como? HTML ou Texto? Se for com `.HtmlBody`, você deve utilizar quebras de linhas html, como o [<br>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Comment: deu certo! caso seja em texto, uso o comando ````vbnewline?````

Comment: Nunca fiz em texto, mas creio que funcionaria. Ou utilizar o `Chr(10)` que é o `vbLf` ou o `Chr(13)` que é o `vbCr`

Comment: beleza! obrigado!

Answer (score -4):

Use a tag `<br>` para quebra de linha, pois e-mail aceita html simples. Outra alternativa é usar o código ansi `"essa parte nao sei se vai funcionar" chr(13)` que equivale ao enter.